# cmake builds the whole project when touching CMakeLists.txt in a subdir

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, project

I have a quite large `c++` project with lots of dependencies. If I have to change something in the `CMakeLists.txt` of one application's subdirectory (nothing else depends on this), on my PC only this application is rebuilt, as expected.

When I do the same thing on the target system, the whole project gets rebuild. After generation, I see that the `flags.make` and `link.txt` in almost all subdirectories have the current timestamp, while on the PC only those in the said directory have been touched.

PC and target run a Debian with `cmake 3.0.2` and use the same configuration; there are just some different flags when `$ARCH` is `armhf`.

How to proceed to find the cause of this problem?

Comment: Do you perform configuration (executing `cmake`) on PC, then move whole directory to the target machine and build it (executing `make`) their? If so, this is wrong workflow: building of the project should be performed on the same machine where it is configured.

Comment: No, I pulled from the same `git` repo and started the same `cmake` configuration steps on both machines.